# What are some ALM alternatives to TFS?

Tags: tfs, alm

I'm also familiar with the 'Subversion + Cruise Control + Fogbugz + nCover + ...' setup used in dev houses. But what other options are there? I'm pretty naive outside of these 2 combinations. I'm from the .net world and perhaps LISP of Ruby developers do it completely differently?

Answer (score 2):

I'm mostly into open-source software stack for developing in .NET (except for the Microsoft Project which does not have any alternatives when you need to handle really complex projects).

In short, primary software ingredients are:

- CruiseControl.NET
- Subversion
- Trac (issues + wiki + SVN) / Google Code for open-source projects
- NCover, NUnit, FxCop, SandCastle, Wix, Lokad Shared Libraries, Autofac, FxCop etc.

**Project management approach:** start projects in a PM style (a lot of planning, clarification and prototyping), get to the first release (minimal functionality, all services are mocked, plain UI), then turn on continuous integration and switch to Agile (while still using PM to plan and schedule on a larger scale).

**Related links:**

- [Software I've been using](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/1/3/development-software-requirements-for-the-xlim-2-solutions.html)
- [Common Development principles](http://abdullin.com/journal/2008/1/8/common-development-principles-for-xlim.html)
- [Component-Driven Development of applications](http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/6/3/developing-component-driven-applications-powered-by-ioc-cont.html)
- [xLim development approach](http://abdullin.com/xlim/)

Answer (score 0):

look [here for Application Life Cycle start point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Lifecycle_Management)

[ALM + TFS Links here](http://blogs.msdn.com/markcarroll/pages/alm-using-vsts-tfs-more-links-than-you-shake-a-stick-at.aspx)

What some people do (me for instance)
is to simply have [Git](http://git-scm.com/)  doing the source version control and perform project management separately with SharePoint (WSS 3.0) or MOSS and/or with Microsoft Office Project

([Windows app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Project), [Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Project_Server))

Comment: I'm after recommendations really: what do other people actually use? The wikipedia link is good for a list of tools, the other link is purely TFS related and I am already familiar with that. I was after user stories with tooling support. Thanks for answering though (no one else has)

Comment: Yes, basically I use Git and Project Server for ALM that and default SharePoint functionality. to be honest, the question should be:

What tools do you use for Application LifeCycle Management?

Comment: TFS is a tool and I asked for alternatives. I'd say that implies tools in the alternatives. :)

Comment: Yes, I think Application Life Cycle Management via Git and Microsoft Office Project implies an alternative methodology in itself.

Comment: Ok because you mentioned that you use MOSS for project management, and PM is different to ALM. I'm more interested in things like support for release management, configuration management, etc. Can you explain how MOSS helps in these scenarios? Because its certainly not built for those purposes.

Comment: that link about tfs + alm is for a post written in 2007 mentioning vs 2005

Answer (score 0):

Concerning code quality checking, architecture exploration, code versions diff and more... you can have a look at [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/).